# Сделать ширину заголовка не шире чем картинка когда изначально их содержимое неизвестно

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="block">
     <h2>Какой-то текст, может быть шире чем картинка ниже</h2>
     <a href="."><img src="test.png"></a>
</div>
```

Текст и картинки динамические.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы ширина block'а определялась шириной картинки, и текст из заголовка переносился, если он шире картинки, не прибегая к js и flex'у?

Comment: А чем флекс не угодил?

Answer (score 2):

http://caniuse.com/#search=intrinsic-width

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Какой-то текст, может быть шире чем картинка ниже</h2>
  <a><img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>АааааааааааааааааааааааааОднострочный</h2>
  <a><img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Но словааааааааааааааааа просто так не разрываются</h2>
  <a><img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: клёво, жаль не кросс-браузерно. хотя бы 11 осла поддержать. Шимы  наверно есть. я вобще, когда столкнулся с этим подумал - да не может быть, чтоб это было сложно.  а оказывается ... а если текст уже картинки? сожмёт картинку?

Comment: @ElmElm, нет, картинке ничего не угрожает. А вот если она не загрузится, то тексту не сдобровать. Шимов, вероятно нет, да и не стал бы я их на css подключать.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать таблицу шириной 1%. В ячейку вставить картинку, которая будет растягивать эту таблицу. А во второй ячейке текст будет подстраиваться под ширину таблицы. В разных браузерах не тестировал, но должно быть максимально кроссбраузерно.

```html
<table style="width: 1%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>
      <img height="92" width="100" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      В чащах юга жил-был цитрус, но фальшивый экземпляр.
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 1%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>
      <img height="92" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      В чащах юга жил-был цитрус, но фальшивый экземпляр.
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с использованием `js` кода. При загрузке страницы считывает ширину картинки и по ней определяет ширину загаловка `h2`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block>h2').css({'width': $('.block>a>img').width()+'px'});
});
```

```css
.block{
  display: inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <h2>Какой-то текст, может быть шире чем картинка ниже</h2>
    <a href="."><img src="http://ceesl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/it-service_icon.png"></a>
</div>
```

Вот второй вариант без `js` и `flex`, но тут размеры картинки могут быть больше чем его настоящие размеры.

```css
.block{
  max-width: 50%;
}

.block img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h2>Какой-то текст, может быть шире чем картинка ниже</h2>
    <a href="."><img src="http://ceesl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/it-service_icon.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: а без js никак?

Comment: @ElmElm Да я видел вопрос что вы хотели без `js`, но при такой структуре я ни как не пойму как можно сделать одну ширину, если конечно ширину картинки не хотите что бы было больше чем его настоящие размеры

Comment: @ElmElm, можно. Один из способов я уже запостил. Про другие надо думать по обстоятельствам.